# how to fixed android pending intent error

Tags: kotlin

my pendding intent code

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, requestCode, arrayOf(intent), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

but log in google console

Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

I'm already writing but it's guiding me to that error

And I googled and added this before

```
 implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
```

What is the reason for that error?